# How to get daily commit count and the number of modified paths from svn repository?

Tags: svn, commit

So what is the easiest way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use [StatSVN](http://www.statsvn.org/) and set up a scheduled task to create nightly reports.

Answer (score 0):

Path of least resistance is to download [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), which supports this out of the box.

From their features page:

> Can create a graph of
>   all revisions/commits. You can then
>   easily see where you created a
>   tag/branch or modified a file/folder
>   Graphs of commit statistics of the
>   project Easy comparing of two branches
>   or tags

Comment: I was kind of hoping to find a way to do it from my scripts.